# How Qt and SystemC event handling interferes?

Tags: qt5, systemc

I am trying to prepare a SystemC application with a QT5 GUI. I have the experience that if I make the call sc_start() in the constructor of a QMainWindow, then all objects receive the Clock signals and work as expected, but QMainWindow does not appear until sc_stop() called.
My guess is that the frequent SystemC events fill thread's event queue. Am I right? Is there any simple way to deal with SystemC events when using Qt5's graphic stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a SystemC in a separate thread. For example you can use C++11 `std::thread`. Use `sc_elab_and_sim` to launch simulation. To communicate with SystemC model asynchronously use `async_request_update`.

Both `sc_elab_and_sim` and `async_request_update` are documented in IEEE-1666 SystemC Standard.